# deleted ubuntu partition from windows 10. now facing error: unknowm file system; entering rescue mode; grub rescue

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, data-recovery

I have a system with dual boot with windows 10 OS and Ubuntu 16.04 server OS in my system. after 1 year ... I found no use of Ubuntu and deleted the ubuntu and extended the drives in windows. so I deleted the Ubuntu OS from the windows 10 formatting disk option. all my important data is there in D, E, and F-Drives of windows 10. now after restarting the system, i am facing error: unknown filesystem; entering rescue mode.....; grub rescue>-

I firstly want to take the back up my data from D, E and F drives and then recover the windows OS.

how to do this.... help me step by step

kindly help.... the data is very important

thanks in advance

Comment: It might be easiest to just recover the lost partition from backup and then do an orderly switchover.

Answer (score 0):

**First step**: Create a Windows 10 boot media, using another computer.

For instructions, see the article
[Create Bootable USB Flash Drive to Install Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2376-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-install-windows-10-a.html).

**Second step**: Boot using the USB into command-line mode to save your files
using `copy` commands.
However, the disks D, E and F may have their letters changed, perhaps to
E, F and G. This step is perhaps not required.

See the article
[How to Open a Command Prompt at Boot in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2880-open-command-prompt-boot-windows-10-a.html)

**Third Step**: Replace the grub boot-loader with that of Windows on disk C.
The D, E and F drives should not be affected by this, only disk C.

See the article
[Run a Startup Repair in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).